# Get data from a script, send to webpage for display

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html index page, which has a form on it. On submit the information is sent to a script (not on the page) for processing. I want this processed data sent back to the webpage to be displayed, but the page is already loaded.  I understand I could send the data to a separate page but I don't want to set up another google script web app.

Is there a way to keep a div from processing until a script function is returned? show? toggle?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input name = "a" type="text"/>
    <input name = "b" type="text"/>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

To the above form you can add an on submit event handler and call preventDefault() on the event to stop the page reload. Then you can make an ajax call to the submit url and then perform your actions on the done promise or the error promise.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).serializeArray());
    $.post('/submit-url',$(this).serializeArray()).done(function(data) {
     //Do something
    }).error(function(data) {
        alert('error');
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/wa0gje29/

Comment: Didn't follow that.  Is there a full example or documentation somewhere?

Comment: Nope. Did you see the fiddle?